# While Loop is running indefinetly and not giving the right Output

Tags: java

I'm just starting out in Java 8 so please excuse my horrendous code. After a few hours of trying this assignment, I'm still not getting any actual results.

The given problem is:

> ABC + DBE = EFF
>
> minus minus minus
>
> DEG + FFA = HFI
>
> equal equal equal
>
> CBI + FED = DEJ

I need to find all the corresponding digits and solve all equations by simply trying out numbers. I can only use While-Loops for this assignment.

Here's the code I came up with:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    int a = 0;
    while (a < 10) {
        
        int b = 0;
        while (b < 10) {
            
            int c = 0;
            while (c < 10) {
                
            int abc = a * 100 + b * 10 + c;

                int d = 0;
                while (d < 10) {
                    
                    int e = 0;
                    while (e < 10) {
                        
                    int dbe = d * 100 + b * 10 + e;
                        
                        int f = 0;
                        while (f < 10) {    
                            
                        int eff = e * 100 + f * 10 + f;
                            
                            int g = 0;
                            while (g < 10) {
                            
                            int deg = d * 100 + e * 10 + g;
                            
                                int ffa = f * 100 + f * 10 + a;
                                
                                    int h = 0;
                                    while (h < 10) {
                                    
                                        int i = 0;
                                        while (i < 10) {
                                        
                                        int hfi = h * 100 + f * 10 + i;
                                        
                                        int cbi = c * 100 + b * 10 + i;
                                            
                                        int fed = f * 100 + e * 10 + d;
                                                
                                        int j = 0;
                                        while (j < 10) {
                                                    
                                        int dej = d * 100 + e * 10 + j;
                                                    
                                            if (abc + dbe == eff &&
                                                deg + ffa == hfi &&
                                                cbi + fed == dej &&
                                                abc - deg == cbi &&
                                                dbe - ffa == fed &&
                                                eff - hfi == dej) {
                                                    
                                                         
                                                 System.out.println(abc);
                                                 System.out.println(dbe);
                                                 System.out.println(eff);
                                                 System.out.println(deg);
                                                 System.out.println(ffa);
                                                 System.out.println(hfi);
                                                 System.out.println(cbi);
                                                 System.out.println(fed);
                                                 System.out.println(dej);
                                                }
                                            }
                                            j++;
                                        }
                                        i++;            
                                    }
                                    h++;
                                }   
                                g++;
                            }
                            f++;  
                        }
                        e++; 
                    }
                    d++; 
                }
                c++;
            }
            b++;
        }
        a++;
    }
}
```

I expect the program to output the values for the combined digits (i.e. abc, dbe, ...), instead the program outputs a never ending stream of seemingly random numbers.

Can you help me find a working solution?

Comment: Hi, try using debugger to find where your program might be calculating the wrong values, also try to divide the nested loops to separated methods, that will give the more readable code (and easier debugging :) )

Comment: I see you get the the right answer, even though, try dividing your problem to submethods (with meaningfull names) you will see that even you code got few additional lines it's easier to read :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start `j++` is outside of the `while (j < 10) {` loop, so it will continue for ever.  This is the same for all other increments.

Also in the first instance, the all the values will be `zero` and thus equals

**output (removing zeros)**

```
602
309
911
398
116
514
204
193
397
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How should I be going about to exclude the zeros in the output?

Comment: Start the loops at 1 rather than 0.

Comment: Luckily only `a` needs changing to `int a = 1;`